# How to obtain the selected date from the following program?

Tags: android

I found the following program from:
http://www.android-examples.com/get-selected-date-from-calendarview-in-android/

```
...

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

CalendarView calender;
TextView textview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

calender = (CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);
textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

calender.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
                                int dayOfMonth) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        textview.setText("Date is : " + dayOfMonth +" / " + (month+1) + " / " + year);

    }
    });
}
}
```

The line:

`textview.setText("Date is : " + dayOfMonth +" / " + (month+1) + " / " + year);`

displays the selected date on the screen.

Is there any way I can get this date the user has selected and use it in the `main activity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to use it outside of `onSelectedDayChange` method scope, for that purpose you can simply create a global object with class level scope and set the values once `onSelectedDayChange` is called something like below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

CalendarView calender;
TextView textview;
TextView textview2;

int selectedYear;
int selectedMonth;
int selectedDay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

calender = (CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);
textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textview2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2); 

calender.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
                            int dayOfMonth) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    selectedYear = year;
    selectedMonth = month;
    selectedDay = dayOfMonth;
    textview.setText("Date is : " + dayOfMonth +" / " + (month+1) + " / " + year);
    showSelectedDate(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay );
}
});
}

public void showSelectedDate(int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay){
    textview2.setText("Date is : " + selectedDay +" / " + (selectedMonth +1) + " / " + selectedYear );
}
}
```

and you can use `selectedYear`, `selectedMonth` and `selectedDay` anywhere inside activity.

Comment: himanshu1496, I mentioned main activity but will it also work for onCreate? I added the following line just before the last 2 braces: textview2.setText("Year is: " + selectedYear); Year is always shown as 0 whereas date is shown correctly. Please advise.

Comment: himanshu1496, I do not know if my question above was clear. Can I send you the code and please let me know what is causing the "Year is" not to update?

Comment: because you need  to call `textview2.setText("Year is: " + selectedYear);` once the date is selected so what you can create a function to set text, which will be called from inside `onSelectedDayChange`.

Comment: or better you can tell me how exactly you want to use the date once it is selected. So that i can tell you the best way to use it

Comment: The date is used to pass onto a sql database in which one of the columns has got the dates. The user selected date is compared with the date in that column and the data for that row is output accordingly. Are you able to show how the function would be written in the inner class for textview2?

Comment: Just what I wanted. I tried to edit one typo but for some reason does not allow me. The 3rd parameter in the inner class should be selectedDay. If you could change it please. Thank you for your help.

Comment: himanshu1496, I made a mistake when I ran the program. As it is, the method is called from Main Activity so it works but I want to call from OnCreate. How should the method be created for that?

Comment: which method you want to call from `onCreate` ?

Comment: I have made a few changes to the code and seem to have got it working now. Thank you for assisting.

Comment: I think you should accept the answer now. Because it answers your basic question.

Answer (score 0):

You are already getting the date details `onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,int dayOfMonth)`.

You can directly use it from here as you are already in an activity.

Comment: Thanks for replying Vishnu. Are you able to show how you would do that?

Comment: What I mean is do you have to create a variable to access the date?

Comment: It depends on your usage , there is no to create variables like 
textview.setText("Date is : " + dayOfMonth +" / " + (month+1) + " / " + year); is used to update a textview without creating new variables

Answer (score 0):

you can create the global variables of day,month and year in your main activity and assign a value to those variable inside onSelectedDayChange listener, So as you can use those variable through out the class.

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare one global String variable.
2. Assign value to that variable where you doing TextView.setText below that

Eg:- String date;

date = dayOfMonth +" / " + (month+1) + " / " + year;

now you can use date through out MainActivity class.